# build.gradle error , Unresolved Dependencies: Failed to resolve: common

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

I am trying to start a hello-world android studio, but have a problem
Unresolved Dependencies:
Failed to resolve: common
Open File

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: try updating `Android SDK Build-Tools-27` in the SDK Tools!

Comment: change 26.1.0 to 26.0.1